# Proxy Settings for TeamSQL

Tags: teamsql

What to add in Proxy Settings for TeamSQL

[image]

Comment: You set it to whatever the settings are for your proxy.

Comment: Am working on my local network without any proxy settings, in this case what we need to provide.